# How to round only when a number ends with nine in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rounding

I want to know if there is a way to round my number only when it ends with `nine`?

For example I have `10.9` it should be rounded to `11`, but if I have `10.8` then it should be not rounded.

Comment: There sure is!  What have you tried?

Comment: I would suggest not using javascript to math... if at all possible, but let me tinker for a minute.

Comment: You need to add a code example to your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Would 3.49 round to 3.5 whereas 3.48 would remain at 3.48?  Is the value for negative number just the reflection of what happens for positive?  You need a more detailed specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the decimal (radix) part of the number.

   - `radix = number % 1.0`
2. Check if `radix` is between `0.9` and `1.0`.

   - Actually use `> 0.8999` instead of `>= 0.9` because `0.9` does not have an exact representation in IEEE-754.
   - Never use `==` with floating-point numbers because they don't have an exact representation.
3. If the radix is between the range, round the input number up using `Math.ceil`

Like so:

```
function roundUpIfDotNine( n ) {

    var radix = n % 1.0;
    if( radix > 0.899 && radix < 1.0 ) {
        return Math.ceil( n );
    }
    else {
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if the number is between .9 and 1 right?

Comment: Something is not working right in my fiddle. It is throwing me off

Comment: Yeah something's not right: `console.log(roundUpIfDotNine(0.1)) // 1`

Answer (score 1):

You coud check value.

```js
function round(v) {
    return Math.floor(v + 0.1) === v + 0.1
        ? v + 0.1
        : v;
}

console.log(round(10.9)); // 11
console.log(round(10.8)); // 10.8
```

Comment: Although not explicitly said, I would imagine the requirement would be to round up anything `.9` *or above*

Answer (score 0):

By converting it to a string temporarily, you could get the last character and check if it's 9:

```
const dontRoundUnlessEndsInNine = (num) => {
    return (String(num).substr(-1) === '9') ? Math.ceil(num) : num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The most shorted solution**

```js
function round(v)
{
    return(''+v).slice(-1) == 9 ? v + 0.1 : v;
}

console.log(round(10.9)); // 11
console.log(round(10.8)); // 10.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I have  small idea of doing this by using JS Functions
AS follows:

```
function qwerty() {

  var number = 11.9;
  var numberStringArr =  number.toString().split(".");

  if(numberStringArr[1] == 9) { // if condition is true, it will add 1
    var num = number + 1;
    var numberStringArr = num.toString().split(".")
    alert(numberStringArr[0]);
  } else {
    alert("No Change");
  }
}
qwerty();
```

A link has been given for JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/2002utewari/0xjh7fp1/